# mysqli_query() espera al menos 2 argumentos, 1 dado al realizar una consulta con Codeigniter4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

Tengo un inconveniente al momento de realizar la consulta en el controlador con la base de datos. Estoy trabajando con Codeigniter 4.
Este es el error:

> mysqli_query() espera al menos 2 argumentos, 1 dado

```
 public function recuperar(){
        $correo = $_POST['usuario'];
        $queryusuario = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$correo'");
        $nr = mysqli_num_rows($queryusuario);
        if ($nr ==1)
        {
            $mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($queryusuario);
            $enviarpassword =$mostrar['password'];

            $paracorreo = $correo;
            $titulo = "Recuperar Contraseña";
            $mensaje = "Tu Contraseña es: ".$enviarpassword;
            $tucorreo = "From: crist09@gmail.com";
            if(mail($paracorreo,$titulo,$mensaje,$tucorreo))
            {
                echo "Contraseña enviada";
            }else
            {
                echo "ERROR";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script> alert ('Este correo no existe');window.location= 'index.php' </script>";
        }
        //VaidrollTeam
    }
```

Comment: Hola, tienes que pasar a `mysqli_query()` dos argumentos: 1. La conexión; 2. La consulta SQL. Solamente estás pasando la consulta. Revisa los ejemplos en el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php). O, mejor aún, empieza a usar el estilo orientado a objetos, que es más claro y evita este tipo de confusiones. En el estilo orientado a objetos la sintaxis sería: `$laConexion->query($laConsultaSQL);`